# ASP.NET web application: Session is resetting only in chrome Version 66.0.3359.181

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, session

My web application was working fine for all browsers but not on latest version of chrome. By doing some debugging, I came to know that session is being reset after post-back. Note that this issue was happening only on deployed version. It was working fine on localhost.

I did some search over the internet and retested the chrome settings (in advance settings) and all started working normal.

Does anyone has nay idea what is there in latest version of chrome which is causing this. Or is there any way to compare the chrome settings on two different computers so that I can reach to a final conclusion.

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering how this issue is related to chrome browser if app dev version is working fine on same browser. Also, check if you have cookies enabled on your chrome browser

Comment: Deployed version was working fine on all other browsers and even on chrome (except version 66). This gives a hint that it is related to latest version only. I checked the cookies and yes they are enabled. Sorry I made a typo in the question, I RESET the settings in chrome and it started working.